# Sort Kendo Multiselects selected Items by DataTextField

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, multi-select

We are using kendo multiselect with mvc wrappers. Everything on the setup works fine, but the selected items are sorted by the data value field. I simply want them to be sorted by the data text field, but nothing worked so far.

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.SelectedPersonIds)
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 400px" })
      .DataTextField("Name")
      .DataValueField("PersonID")
      .Filter("contains")
      .Height(400)
      .DataSource(ds =>
      {
       ds.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetPersons", "Person", new { area = "" });
        });
      })
      .ItemTemplateId("detailTemplate")
      .TagTemplateId("valueTemplate")
)
```

This is the working version. I tried adding

```
ds.Custom().Sort(s => s.Add("Name").Ascending());
```

and other approaches, but still no luck. The initial data, coming from the server, is sorted and therefore the list you select from is sorted perfectly (by Name).

How can i achieve that the *selected* items are also sorted by Name instead of by ID?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know is there is ASP.NET solution but i can give you JavaScript to solve it:

```
function onMultiselectChange(e) {
        e.sender.tagList.find('> li').sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).text() > $(b).text();
        }).appendTo(e.sender.tagList);
    }
});
```

You can apply it to your ASP.NET multiselect like this:

```
.Events(e =>
    {
        e.Change("onMultiselectChange")
    })
```

Comment: Would be nice to have more sophisticated and efficient way to sort the selected items

Comment: Keep in mind that this will sort only the tag list, but it does not change the underlying data structure. When you delete a tag from the multiselect you might delete a different item from the actual multiselect based on the original index and the current index after sorting the tag list. That way the tag list you see it not the same as the underlying data structure, which is the one being send back to the server when used in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Do not manually rearrange the DOM elements. Doing this will break the mapping between the displayed items and the internal data. If you were to manually rearrange the DOM elements, then deselecting an item will cause a different data item to be deselected in the underlying data. Binding back to the server will yield incorrect results.

Here is a correct way to order it, given that the value field is `PersonID` but you want it sorted by `Name`

```
function orderMultiSelect(multi) {
    const dataItems = multi.dataItems();
    dataItems.sort(
        (a, b) => {
            const textA = a.Name;
            const textB = b.Name;
            return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    );
   const values = dataItems.map(di => di.PersonID);
   multi.value(values);
}

function onMultiselectChange(e) {
    orderMultiselect(e.sender);
}
```

You would then bind this handler function to the to the `DataBound` and `Change` events:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.SelectedPersonIds)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 400px" })
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("PersonID")
    .Filter("contains")
    .Height(400)
    .DataSource(
        ds =>
        {
           ds.Read(
              read =>
                  read.Action("GetPersons", "Person", new { area = "" })
             );
        }
      ).ItemTemplateId("detailTemplate")
      .TagTemplateId("valueTemplate")
      .Event(
          e => 
            e.DataBound("onMultiselectChange")
              .Change("onMultiselectChange")
      )
)
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0gS9SDeccgOmfsGp?preview